# Dispatch two elements in one action

Tags: vue.js

I want to dispatch `dateFor` and `ItemsArray` to the action in the store i.e. `selectItem`. The code is like this

```
pushItems: function (dateFor) {
      var ItemsArray = this.selectItem
      this.$store.dispatch('selectItem', dateFor, ItemsArray)
    }
```

In action of store,

```
selectItem: function ({ commit }, newDate, newSelectItem) {
      var selectNew = {
        dateFor: newDate,
        ItemsArray: newSelectItem
      }
      console.log('Check', newDate, newSelectItem)
      commit('selectNew', selectNew)
    }
```

But I can only get the value of the first argument passed in the function, in here that is `newDate`. I need to be able to pass both the values. Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

You could use object destructuring method to pass the values and it should be accurate to get the value based on the key name. see code below

```
this.$store.dispatch('selectItem', 
  {
    newDate: dateFor, 
    newSelectItem: ItemsArray
  }
)
```

Then

```
selectItem: function ({ commit }, {newData, newSelectItem}) {
  var selectNew = {
    dateFor: newData,
    ItemsArray: newSelectItem
  }

  console.log('Check', newData, newSelectItem)
  commit('selectNew', selectNew)
}
```

Comment: Happy coding :)

Comment: Need an extra help ! In mutation, doing this
 `
 selectNew: function (state, { newDate, newSelectItem }) {
      console.log('suru', newSelectItem)
} 
`
shows undefined too. Any specifics?

Comment: you must pass an object having a key newSelectItem, else it will return error

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thanks !